# How to disable Symantec Endpoint Protection antivirus?

Tags: windows, symantec, anti-virus

I am running Symantec Endpoint Protection under Windows XP. Even when I click "Disable Symantec Endpoint Protection" on tray-menu, antivirus still doesn't allow to copy files which it finds suspicious. I wonder how to disable Symantec Endpoint Protection antivirus for a while without uninstalling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it managed by a corporate AV server? Sometimes the ability to disable it is controlled by policy and not something the end user can change even if they are an administrator.

Comment: Yep, it seems that it is the case.

Comment: @bublegumn - You can accept this answer as correct if you would like by clicking the check mark icon underneath the voting next to my answer.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to turn off this policy

Comment: Usually if this is mandated from a policy server there is no way to disable it temporarily. You can try disabling the service in msconfig and rebooting, but then you will be completely unprotected. The right way to handle this is ask the administrator of your anti-virus server to make an exception for the files that you would like to copy.